# Create separate Table for each key in Data Stream after doing keyBy operation in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

My requirement is to create separate tables for each key in two different data streams and then join them. I have successfully created two separate tables from the data streams in Flink and performed the join using table api. However, I am facing difficulty in creating separate tables for each key.

Is there a way to create individual tables for each key in the data stream?

I have followed [tutorial](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/) to create tables from data streams, but I'm not sure how to proceed with creating separate tables for each key. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am also interested in receiving suggestions and learning about best practices for managing multi-tenancy in Flink.

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of keys in advance, or is the key space dynamic? How many distinct keys might there be?

Comment: Can you explain why you need separate, per-key tables? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve the ultimate goal.

Comment: key space is dynamic and it can be around a hundred. The use case is I'm doing some ETL processing by doing keyBy using the tenant. So, I need a separate table for each tenant.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to handle multi-tenancy in Flink while doing ETL processing? Which is suggested, running a separate job for each tenant or doing keyBy operation?

Comment: I don’t think there is one best answer to this question. There are lots of factors to consider.